# Job search: How long to keep conversations open?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-change

My current role is going away, but I'd like to stay at the company and the company would probably keep me if they could find a place for me. So I have spoken to a lot of colleagues who manage teams. A few are interested in making space for me, but nothing is certain yet.

Faced with this uncertainty, I've been sending out resumes and reaching out to my network regarding external opportunities. Some of those conversations are heating up: Phone screenings, onsite interviews. Etc.

If a reasonable internal role opened up, I'd take it. If reasonable internal and truly fantastic external opportunities both came up, I'd weigh them carefully. And if no internal role opened up, of course I'd take an external role.

Is it unethical to continue the external conversations, potentially wasting interviewers' time because of my preference for internal opportunities? Or should I push all the conversations to their utmost? Should I communicate about external opportunities with internal managers, in the hopes of creating some urgency?

I wish I'd taken a class in game theory.

Comment: Also voting to close. They are just different applications with preference for staying.  You should not have to tell your company you are looking for another job.  If your role is going away that is what most people would do.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to continue your job search in all possible areas until you have accepted a written job offer.

Recruiters, especially for large companies with office positions, know that a job applicant is almost never focused on just one company, and that at any moment you could accept a job offer somewhere else. They (usually) understand and will simply move on to their next candidate. If you receive a job offer from them (but haven't accepted it), you can even use that as leverage to accelerate your current company's own HR processes if they are bent on keeping you within the company.

Really, the only possibility for your search to be unethical is if you have already accepted a job offer and are considering reneging on it.

Comment: This is great feedback. I agree with the commenters above that, for the most part, this question is the same as "how to deal with multiple job offers". Thanks!